# Options Pattern using Options Builder

Tags: c#, .net

I try to find out how .Net Dependency injection resolve `IOption<TOption>` from `OptionsBuilder<TOptions>` and I can not find something in documentation and APIs of .Net. How it relates `OptionsBuilder` to that. For example consider this line:

```
new OptionsBuilder<Settings>(builder.Services, String.Empty)
.Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("settings"));
```

I created an option builder instance and config it to bind to `IConfiguration` section.
Then in one of my controllers I injected `IOptions<settings>` and it resolved as I want. Where is the missed Link? I could not find any link between options Builder and Options Factory or Options Manager types in `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` namespace, so it should be something internal to DI I thing. Where is that link since .Net is open source now and all the code is in GitHub as it is implemented.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to code for `AddOptions` we have the following registration for this extension methods:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddOptions(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(services);

    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptions<>), typeof(UnnamedOptionsManager<>)));
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped(typeof(IOptionsSnapshot<>), typeof(OptionsManager<>)));
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptionsMonitor<>), typeof(OptionsMonitor<>)));
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(IOptionsFactory<>), typeof(OptionsFactory<>)));
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptionsMonitorCache<>), typeof(OptionsCache<>)));
    return services;
}
```

So when we inject `IOptions<TOption>` it try to inject an instance of it which is `UnnamedOptionManager<TOption>`. And to create an instance of it, it constructor require `OptionsFactory` to be injected to it and constructor of `OptionFactory` itself requires to all the Configuration Action and Post Configuration action and Validations to be injected. This is all needed. So all the remain is how we register `IConfigureOptions`. It can be done in the following ways Using Options Builder and Using `Configure/PostConfigure/Validate/ConfigureOptions` extension methods of service collection:

1. Using Options Builder: In this approach, we create an option builder using its constructor which requires service collection and Options name (or using `service.AddOptions<TOptions>()` extension method which return an Option Builder). Then we configure this option Builder using Configure, PostConfigure and Validate or Bind method in a chained manner (These methods is different than the one which defined (Configure, PostConfigure, ConfigureOptions, ConfigureAll, PostConfigureAll) for service collection as extension methods). Every method of OptionsBuilder do this internally:
   `service.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions>()` and calling `AddOptions()`.
2. Using extension method defined for service container (`Configure`, `PostConfigure`, `ConfigureOptions`, `ConfigureAll`, `PostConfigureAll`) which is as below almost:

   ```cs
   // Configure Extension method of Services Collection
   public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, string? name, Action<TOptions> configureOptions)
       where TOptions : class
   {
       ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(services);
       ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(configureOptions);
       services.AddOptions();
       services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>>(new ConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions>(name, configureOptions));
       return services;
   }
   ```

So the answer to the question is the definition `AddOptions()` and definition of every method of `OptionsBuilder`.